# Create a new list with changes of value of a previous list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list with floats, for example

```
numbers = [1000.45,1002.98,1005.099,1007.987]
```

I want to create a new list containing the deltas of the value in numbers - i.e. I want the difference between numbers[0],[numbers[1] to be the first value in a new list. So the first number in my new list should be 2.53, the second should be 2.119, and so forth.

I tried list comprehension

```
newnumbers= [i[-1] - i[-2] for i in numbers]
```

but it gives a TypeError

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried converting the list to integers, but then it gives the same type of error.

How can I create my desired list?

Comment: `for i in numbers` gives you each float. You can't index that. You could do `for i in range(len(numbers))`, and then use `numbers[i-1]` and `numbers[i]`. But then you have to be careful about the boundaries (what happens at the start, when `i` is 0?)

Comment: A better solution is to just `zip` two copies of `numbers` together, one of them shifted ahead by one. (You can do this with slicing, or look in the `itertools` recipe for a way to do it without making a copy of your whole list.) Then you just loop over that zip and you get all the adjacent pairs, so you just subtract.

Comment: i wish to point that unnecessary imports should be avoided, so even the answer with pandas is working its totally overkill for the task and should not be accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for i in numbers` i is equal to 1000.45 in the first loop, then 1002.98 etc. So `i[-1] = 1000.45[-1]` which means nothing, you cannot subscriptable a float

```
numbers = [1000.45,1002.98,1005.099,1007.987]
newnumbers= [numbers[i+1]-numbers[i] for i in range(len(numbers)-1)]
print(newnumbers)
#[2.5299999999999727, 2.119000000000028, 2.88799999999992]
```

If you want 2 decimal points

```
newnumbers= [float("%0.2f"%(numbers[i+1]-numbers[i])) for i in range(len(numbers)-1)]
#[2.53, 2.12, 2.89]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with Pandas, use `diff()`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(numbers).diff()

0      NaN
1    2.530
2    2.119
3    2.888
dtype: float64
```

Comment: it's true but you don't need to import anything here - it's one-liner - @liamvharris answer shows that

Comment: @liamvharris's answer is great.  In this case I find the Pandas approach is semantically clearer - and importing Pandas isn't so bad.  But you're right, there's nothing wrong with pure Python!

Comment: yeah - if you use pandas for other things as well in your project its best for these type of tasks, but importing it for only this one place where one-liner does job is overkill and unnecessary slows down solution :) - I suggest you guys combine your answers with note about use-cases

Comment: I agree with @Drako, I selected the pandas answer first because I already had pandas imported in the script.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but just haven't quite got the syntax right. You should use:

```
newnumbers = [(numbers[i] - numbers[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(numbers))]
```

In your version you're trying to index a number, but you need to index your list instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
newnumbers  = []
for i in range(1,len(numbers)-1):
    newnumbers.append(numbers[i]-numbers[i-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Note how you access your elements *directly*, instead of using list indices;
The correct way to do the latter in Python would be

```
for index in range(len(numbers)):
```

What you are using is essentially the numbers themselves. Also, note that you would have to exclude the first index of your list, since you only want the differences (otherwise, the first call would look at the last index again, according to Python's behavior of calling `mylist[-1]`), which is why you can restrict your range to `range(1,len(numbers))`. In the form of a list comprehension, it would now work like this:

```
newnumbers = [numbers[i] - numbers[i-1] for i in range(1,len(numbers))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that doesn't require importing any modules:

```
numbers = [1000.45,1002.98,1005.099,1007.987]
sliced = numbers[1:]

answer = list(map((lambda x,y: y - x),sliced,numbers))
```

This gives:

```
[-2.5299999999999727, -2.119000000000028, -2.88799999999992]
```

You can then do:

```
final_answer = [round(x,2) for x in answer]
```

which gives:

```
[-2.53, -2.12, -2.89]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> numbers = [1000.45,1002.98,1005.099,1007.987]
>>> [round((y-x),2) for x,y in zip(numbers, numbers[1:])]
[2.53, 2.12, 2.89]
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation rather than code only.